# webpack-dev-server inline flag doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I've got an extremely simple webpack setup, I'm trying to make automatic reload work. I've got all files in the root directory of the project, to keep things simple.

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Webpack</title>
  </head>
  <body>hello</body>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    javascript: "./app.js",
    html: "./index.html",
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js"
  }, 
  watch: true,
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: "file?name=[name].[ext]",
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

and `app.js`:

```
console.log("hello everyone!");
```

To run webpack, I execute:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --inline
```

When I change any of the files, I can see `webpack-dev-server` recompiles, which works fine. However, I still need to refresh the whole page to update new content. I thought I should not need to do that, when using `--inline` option.

I found out that if I add following line to my html:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>
```

then auto-reload works fine. But html should **NOT** contain this line, becuase:

- it should not get into the repo, not to modify html itself
- `inline` should handle that. Either CLI param or the attribute in `webpack.config.js` file. I used both, neither works.

I don't know why the `inline` thing doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Webpack Dev Server inline mode depends on publicPath.
You can add publicPath in your webpack.conf, and address your js file like this: `<script src="assets/app.js"></script>`.
Then the inline mode will work.

Comment: I know about `publicPath` from the docs, but still I don't know what to define there. SO is example-based, regarding both questions and answers. Your answer doesn't help me - as for now. It might be a comment, but it's not an answer as-is